# crystal formula with local variable

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table with 4 columns (Morning/Afternoon/Evening/Night)char(1) field data will Y/N in the column.

With this table I am creating a crystal report 
The output should be something like this:

```
if Morning and night is Y

Mor.........Night (nine dots)

If only Morning is Y 
Mor ( not dots)

If Afternoon and Evening
...Afternoon...Evening

if Morning and Evening
Mor......Evening(6 dots between mor and ever )

if Morning Afternoon evening and night is Y
Mor...After...Eve...Night
```

Like this I want in crystal report. 
I tried like this but not working properly
in cystal report formula editor:

```
    local stringvar flag;
if {Table.Morning}='Y' then
flag:='Mor'
else
flag:='...'

if {Table.Afternoon}='Y' then
flag:=Flag+'after'
else
flag:=flag;
```

But is not as per desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of multiple **If-else if** statements to accomplish this

```
if {Table.Morning}='Y' then 'Mor'
else if ({Table.Morning}='Y' and {Table.night}='Y')  then 'Mor.........Night'
else if ({Table.Afternoon}='Y' and {Table.Evening}='Y')  then 'Afternoon...Evening'
else if ({Table.Morning}='Y' and {Table.Evening}='Y')  then 'Mor......Evening'
else if ({Table.Morning}='Y' and {Table.Afternoon}='Y' and {Table.evening}='Y' and {Table.night}='Y')  then 'Mor...After...Eve...Night'
else ''
```

Comment: Hexx
Yes I can do like this but then I will have to write atleast sixteen conditions four for each I was trying make it in some other way instead of 16 else if

Comment: @YousufKhan Edit Your question and add complete information.